# userControl repeated with Form tag disappearing

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms

I have a Contact userControl that have "save contact" as submit button and fields inside form tag we repeat this userControl with Code 20 times in one page

My problem is the Form Tag in the first userControl is hiding somehow --- i checked the userControl with developer Tool IE9 , firebug Firefox7 and the Form is not appearing in the first userControl and its appearing with the rest 19 Controls

I tried to **View Source** and take html copy in new html file in VS -- i found form is exist

i dont know if iam clear enough but please advice if you need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a form tag at the server, inside a user control, and then displaying this user control more than once on the page, then you will have multiple form tags running at server on one page, which is not allowed by ASP.NET

Take the form tag outside of the user control like:

```
<form runat="server">
  <uc:Contact />
  <uc:Contact />
  <uc:Contact />
</form>
```

Comment: We add the user control programatically and the problem is not that the control is hidden after the post back, the problem is that the client side validation is working on all user controls except for the first one!! --Note: Mahmoud is my team mate

Comment: Please can you provide source code for the user control and the code which is programatically adding the user controls?